# how to find multiple comma separated string in main string

Tags: php, string

I have this main sting.

```
S,SR,DSR,DS,FX,FXS,SR,DS,S,SR,DS,FX,S,SR,DS,FX,FXS
```

and i want to find each of the following strings ..

`DSR` and `FXS`

i have tried by following code but it can not given me perfect result.

code...

```
<?php
    $mainstring ="S,SR,DSR,DS,FX,FXS,SR,DS,S,SR,DS,FX,S,SR,DS,FX,FXS";
    $needed = "DSR,FXS";

    if( strpos( $mainstring, $needed ) !== false ) {
        echo "Found";
    }else{
        echo "Not match";
    }
?>
```

Comment: "DSR,FXS" isn't in your string...

Comment: if( strpos( $mainstring, $needed ) !== false ) is not the smartest way, because if $mainstring is starting with $needed, strpos will return 0, which is == false.

Comment: "DSR,FXS" is available in main string look at " S,SR,DSR,DS,FX,FXS,SR,DS,S,SR,DS,FX,S,SR,DS,FX,FXS ".

Comment: no, "DSR" is available, and "FXS" is available, but "DSR,FXS" is not.

Comment: They are available separately, but not in the correct order,  strpos looks for `DSR,FXS` not `DSR` and then `FXS`

Comment: i would like to find separately.

Comment: Follow @Matei Mihai

Comment: @kosta, fyi, the `!==` and `===` (triple equal) check the types of the values as well as the value. Therefore 0 (int zero) is different than false (boolean).

Comment: @RyanVincent, you're right.

Answer (score 5):

One solution would be to explode those strings by comma and verify if the resulted arrays intersection count is the same as your search:

```
$mainstring ="S,SR,DSR,DS,FX,FXS,SR,DS,S,SR,DS,FX,S,SR,DS,FX,FXS";
$needed = "DSR,FXS";

$mainStringArr = explode(',', $mainstring);
$neededArr = explode(',', $needed);

if (count(array_unique(array_intersect($mainStringArr, $neededArr))) == count($neededArr)) {
    echo 'found';
} else {
    echo 'not found';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Explode the `$needed` string by command and traverse the array to and compare each value of array into `$mainstring` using `strpos()` function. If found then put that value into `$arrResut` with 'Found' or 'not found' value and finally print the `$arrResult` to view which value of $needed is found and which is not.

Also, we increment `$cntNeeded` variable if value if found. at the end of `foreach` loop compare value of `$cntNeeded` & `$arrNeeded` are same then all values are found into `$mainstring` else not.

```
$mainstring ="S,SR,DSR,DS,FX,FXS,SR,DS,S,SR,DS,FX,S,SR,DS,FX,FXS";
$needed = "DSR,FXS";
$arrNeeded = explode(",", $needed);

$arrResult = array();
$cntNeeded = 0;
foreach($arrNeeded as $index => $needed) {
  if( strpos( $mainstring, $needed ) !== false ) {
    $arrResult[$needed] = "Found";
    $cntNeeded++;
  }
  else{
    $arrResult[$needed] = "Not match";
  }
}

print("<pre> :: arrResult ::");
print_r($arrResult);
print("</pre>");

if($cntNeeded == count($arrNeeded)) {
  echo "Found";
}
else {
  echo "Not match";
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try below code"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.